# How to generate a list of possible tags?

Tags: php, tags, keyword

My site needs to develop a extensive list of keywords and key phrases related to it's industry so that when users post about certain things, the post can be tagged relevantly.

Aside from manually creating a list of thousands of words and phrases, what is a common practice for generating such a list?

Is it done by parsing posts into common keywords, or something else?

THOUGHT:

I would seem that relying on the parsing of posts as they are posted would be fairly limiting at first, and would mean that only after developing the content on the site longer, would I have a decent keyword list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ask for the help of the user; when a user posts a message, he or she can select tags that already exist and add new ones. The new ones can appear directly or can go to a queue to be moderated by you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to train an expert system, probably a Bayesian classifier, to classify documents (tag) similar to how experts (humans) have classified similar documents.  However, you need human training so you should get that working first.  Then you will probably find that trying to recommend tags to users is a lot of work and error-prone and skip that part.